# Why do my faked button presses fail with SendMessage?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to send mouse events to a window in windows through the [`SendMessage(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

The problem I'm facing is that the messages don't seem to be delivered to the window I'm sending them to, even though `SendMessage` returns `0`, which(according to the documentation) means the message was delivered successfully.

I'm using the following piece of code:

(Let `p` be a `Point` struct and `selectedWindow.Handle` a valid handle to a window)

```
int position = ((p.X & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (p.Y & 0xFFFF);

SendMessage(selectedWindow.Handle, 0x0201, new IntPtr(), new IntPtr(position));
SendMessage(selectedWindow.Handle, 0x0202, new IntPtr(), new IntPtr(position));
```

`0x0201` and `0x0202` are [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WM_LBUTTONUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645608%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Could someone enlighten me why this isn't working?

(Edit: I **am** using the `ScreenToClient()` method to convert a screen position to a position within the window)

Comment: I think you're right. A function that has been part of the Windows API for something like 20 years probably doesn't work, and you're the first to notice. ;) (in other words, your question title might be more accurate if you asked how to use the function, rather than asking if it works *at all*)

Comment: @jalf: I didn't end the question with a question mark for nothing :p!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mouse messages are normally retrieved from the message queue, which means you should use PostMessage().  But it isn't that likely that this is the real problem, very few programs do mouse handling in the message loop.  UAC is an obvious failure scenario, you cannot send messages to a window owned by an elevated program.  You send the wrong WParam value, that could have an effect.  And of course you could have the wrong window handle.

But the much more likely cause is the code we cannot see.  You seem to go through some trouble to generate the X- and Y-coordinates of the message.  No such effort is necessary, it doesn't matter *where* you click the button.  You might as well click it at (1, 1):

```
 PostMessage(selectedWindow.Handle, 0x0201, new IntPtr(1), new IntPtr(0x10001));
 PostMessage(selectedWindow.Handle, 0x0202, new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0x10001));
```

Or in other words, mouse coordinates are relative from the window's upper left corner.  Additional hacks are generating the BM_CLICK message and whatever WM_COMMAND message the button generates.

Use the Spy++ tool to observe the message processing.

Answer (score 3):

I have three suggestions:

First, make sure that the coordinates are relative to the origin of the window's client area.  If you're using screen coordinates, you must first use the ScreenToClient function to convert them.

Second, try using PostMessage instead of SendMessage.  This more closely emulates the actual behavior of Windows.

Finally, unless you are absolutely opposed to moving the actual mouse pointer, you may find it easier to use the mouse_event or SendInput function.

Comment: I'll try to use `PostMessage` tommorow. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This didn't work either. It think it has something to do with the security of Windows, so that only the thread that created the window is able to send events?