# Virtual mouse click on a window covered by another window

Tags: c#, mouseevent

Is that even possible (C#)? The window, I want to click on is of course not mimized but just covered with another window. I can just assume, that it has something to do with window handle. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do my faked button presses fail with SendMessage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479941/why-do-my-faked-button-presses-fail-with-sendmessage)

Comment: Investigate using the `SendInput` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but you would have to use Windows API to get pointer to that window (assuming that you know what window your are looking for and it's part of a different application).

On the other hand, why would you need to "emulate mouse click on other window"?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yea, I've got that window's pointer, mainwindowhandle and and process'es handle (using all of em) but still, I dont know what next :p